# Contact View Styling on Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

Ok, currently I have a view in my android app that displays a list of contacts for our agents that is retrieved via a web service.

I have built a simple array adapter that binds my contact objects to the listactivity and just uses a contactrow.xml template to display anywhere from 1 to 1000 contacts.

This works fine but is *lacking* at best.  I want to replicate the way that contacts are scrolled in the android contact app.  Is there is way to have the ABC's indexed to the right and help the end user navigate this contact list the same way they would expect?

Does the CursorAdapter help accomplish this?  What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [AlphabetIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html) class. I've not used it personally, but here is a tutorial that may help you:

http://www.anddev.org/tutusing_alphabetindexer_for_fastscrolling_listview-t10282.html

Comment: Exactly!  I will look into how to get the alphabet to appear on the right side but this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: It appears on the right side by default when you scroll. Unless, of course, you're talking about having a bar that is always visible on the right (e.g. the iPhone)?

Comment: yea.  on some of the droid contact apps it appears as well, like an index.  not sure how to simulate that but it isnt a show stopper at this point.  it would be a nice to have though.