# Making list view as contact list in android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a list view as same as contact list of android phone. Where all names are categorized by alphabetic. And they are be able to populate while clicking on an alpha bate.
How can this be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [Contact View Styling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146906/contact-view-styling-on-android)

Comment: http://umakantpatil.com/posts/android-listview-with-separate-headers-and-images-loading-from-remote-server

Comment: Use of sectionIndexer ( Best alternative  of making header in list )             http://www.anddev.org/tutalphabetic_fastscroll_listview_-_similar_to_contacts-t10123.html    http://www.anddev.org/tutusing_alphabetindexer_for_fastscrolling_listview-t10282.html

Comment: @Pixie - Please summarize the text that you linked to in your answer. If that link breaks, so does your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Contact List View with Pinned Header 
[ContactList](http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2012/08/android-pinned-header-listview.html)